# Creating Facebook Sharing Buttons

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a share button on my website so that a user will be able to share the page to facebook but am having some difficulty understanding how to do this correctly.

On this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button the code for a button gets automatically generated however you are only allowed three or four different looks for the button and none of these fits what I am going for.

I also found this post http://logicum.co/creating-custom-share-buttons-facebook-twitter-google/

On this page there is some code that you would add to where you want the share button to be. I followed the instructions on this page but when I try to share to facebook I do not get the normal share pop up like this:

[image]

Instead my browser opens up a new page that looks like this:

[image]

Here is my code for the button

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100" target="_blank" id="u_0_1"><img src="Images/facebook_logo.png" /></a>
```

I added the meta tags as described in this post: http://www.phpscholar.com/tutorials/custom-thumbnail-title-and-description-for-facebook-share-using-open-graph

like this :

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://localhost:81/Index.php" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Clothing" />
<meta property="og:description" content="South African streetwear by South African streetwear lovers" />
<meta property="og:image" content="Images/logo_thumbnail.png" />
```

This is the original code I got from the facebook developers site, it provides a working share button that opens the popup but does not allow me to specify the image used as the icon:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="share-box"><div class="fb-share-button" data-type="icon" data-href="http://localhost:81/DopeClothing/Index.php" data-width="30"></div></div>
```

All I want to do is have a share button on my page where I can specify the image to use so that it fits with my look and feel

Comment: You include the Facebook JS SDK so you can invoke the share dialog using `FB.ui()` in an onclick handle on any element. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your solution :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fbs_click(width, height) {
    var leftPosition, topPosition;
    //Allow for borders.
    leftPosition = (window.screen.width / 2) - ((width / 2) + 10);
    //Allow for title and status bars.
    topPosition = (window.screen.height / 2) - ((height / 2) + 50);
    var windowFeatures = "status=no,height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",resizable=yes,left=" + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",screenY=" + topPosition + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no";
    u=location.href;
    t=document.title;
    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer', windowFeatures);
    return false;
}
</script>

<!-- Please change the width and height to suit your needs -->
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<full page url to share>" onClick="return fbs_click(500, 300)" target="_blank" title="Share This on Facebook"><img src="yourimage.jpg" alt="facebook share"></a>
```